# Why does "a[-1]" = 17

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm working through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial and this is the first time I've seen the last item in an array referred to as being "-1" indexed. How is this calculated?
[image: Why does "a[-1]" = 17]

Comment: it's just exactly what you already said, negative indexes count from the end of the array. That's it. You already figured it out.

Comment: @Kim I _highly_ suggest you learn Ruby before entering a RoR tutorial. Even though it seems like you are learning Ruby right now, you will get more out of RubyMonk or something.

Answer (score 3):

It references from the end of the array, so:

```
 a[-2] == 8      # true
 a[-3] == 42     # true
```

A side note, if you're a java user, you would appreciate not doing something like this to index arrays:

```
 a[a.length-2]   # 8
```

Comment: This is correct. See [Ruby Quicktips: Use negative array indicies](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/996814716/use-negative-array-indices) for more information.

Comment: @ergonaut a[-3] == 42?

Comment: @Kim: Why don't you just try it out? Also, if there is something unclear about the documentation, I'm sure the Ruby documentation team would like to know about it!

Comment: Kim, it's the 3rd from the right hand side.  a[0] == a[-3], a[1] == a[-2], a[2] == a[-1]

Answer (score 0):

It is because ruby is different that other programming languages. 
The inventor of ruby believed that is a useful feature to be able to get elements from the end of an array, so he implemented it this way.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your insight. @mu is too short...as a newbie I am still trying to figure out all things related to programming...including Stack Overflow best practices. Again thank you and I appreciate the effort you all make to help those in coding need :-)